# IntelliJ rename in Java with Spock tests - doesn't rename test file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, spock

When I refactor Java class name in IntelliJ in project where I have tests in Spock I do not get Spec file renamed at all.
E.g. class `FilteredRequest` with `FilteredRequestSpec` after refactoring class name, the spec name stays the same.

Is that possible to make that working?

Answer (score 2):

If it is called `FilteredRequestTest` then it will be found by IntelliJ when "Rename Tests" is checked in the rename dialog.

If it is called `FilteredRequestSpec`, then it won't be found or renamed.

This seems like a bug, as the "Create New Test" dialog finds the `FilteredRequestSpec` test fine...

Indeed there is [a bug report on the IntelliJ bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116536) which you could vote up